# xml ftplugin overrides textwidth

Tags: formatting, wrapping, line-breaks, filetype-xml

I would like to hard wrap XML files during editing. In every other filetype my `set textwidth=80` works fine. But in XML something overrides the insertion of line breaks. I tried adding `t` to `formatoptions` but that doesn't make a difference. I believe there is an automatic formatting command being called from the default xml filetype plugin, which overrides all else.

How can I set up vim to do automatic line breaking in XML?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the xml filetype plugin disables auto wrapping text using textwidth with the following:

```
setlocal formatoptions-=t
```

This removes the option `t` (= "Auto-wrap text using textwidth") from formatoptions. See `:help formatoptions` and `:help fo-table`.

To overwrite do the following:

Create the file `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/xml.vim` (or `$HOME/vimfiles/after/ftplugin/xml.vim` on Windows) with the following content:

```
" prevent multiple loading
if exists("b:did_my_ftplugin") | finish | endif
let b:did_my_ftplugin = 1

setlocal formatoptions+=t
```

The files in `~/.vim/after` are loaded after the default plugins are loaded. So this can be used to overwrite settings done in the default ftplugin. See `:help after-directory`.
Here the option `t` is readded to `formatoptions`.

Comment: I found I also needed `setlocal formatoptions-=l` and `setlocal formatexpr=`. This of course disables automatic formatting. It also seems to break auto indentation (disable with `setlocal indentexpr=`). Maybe the XML plugin needs patching? Or is there another solution?

Comment: @tbrk xml filetype maintainer here. Why do you think you need patching?

Comment: Hello @ChristianBrabandt, when I enabled hard line wrapping using the options given above, the automatic tag indentation started to behave strangely. However, I just found that there is a tag indentation problem on my Mac even before changing any options and that tag indentation + hard line wrapping works fine on my Linux box (`fo+=t, fo-=l, formatexpr=`; both using Vim 8.1). I take back my comment about the XML plugin needing paching. Sorry for the noise!

Comment: The `fo+=t` flag in the after/ftplugin file greatly improves the experience of editing xml files!